# JTabbedpane in JSplitPane

Tags: java, jtabbedpane, jsplitpane

Respected Developers,

I am developing a NASA World Wind application for desktop. 
I have tried to put a JSplitPane where in the lower Panel displays the result and the upper one displays the canvas is in two sections. The left component contains the layer list and the right component contains the canvas. I have been trying to insert a JTabbedPane in the left component so as to have different options like the layer list, SQL query list and many more. I am unable to add and view the frame of the JTabbedPane on the left Panel.

I am attaching my code for reference.

All help is appreciated.

**CODE BLOCK**

```
public AppFrame()
        {
            /*------------------------------------INITIALIZATION OF THE MAIN FRAME------------------------------------*/
            this.initialize(false, true, false);

            /*---------------------------------------SPLIT PANE AND PANEL CODE---------------------------------------*/
            // Create a horizontal split pane containing the layer panel and the WorldWindow panel.
            JSplitPane horizontalSplitPane = new JSplitPane();
            horizontalSplitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
            JTabbedPane tp=new JTabbedPane();
            horizontalSplitPane.setLeftComponent(tp);
            horizontalSplitPane.setRightComponent(wwjPanel);
            horizontalSplitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
            horizontalSplitPane.setContinuousLayout(true);// prevents the pane's being obscured when expanding right

            // Create a panel for the bottom component of a vertical split-pane.
            JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Bottom Panel");
            label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            bottomPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            // Create a vertical split-pane containing the horizontal split plane and the button panel.
            JSplitPane verticalSplitPane = new JSplitPane();
            verticalSplitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
            verticalSplitPane.setTopComponent(horizontalSplitPane);
            verticalSplitPane.setBottomComponent(bottomPanel);
            verticalSplitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
            verticalSplitPane.setContinuousLayout(true);
            verticalSplitPane.setResizeWeight(1);

            // Add the vertical split-pane to the frame.
            this.getContentPane().add(verticalSplitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            this.pack();

            // Center the application on the screen.
            Dimension prefSize = this.getPreferredSize();
            Dimension parentSize;
            java.awt.Point parentLocation = new java.awt.Point(0, 0);
            parentSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            int x = parentLocation.x + (parentSize.width - prefSize.width) / 2;
            int y = parentLocation.y + (parentSize.height - prefSize.height) / 2;
            this.setLocation(x, y);
            this.setResizable(true);

            /*-------------------------------------------PATH CREATION CODE-------------------------------------------*/
            // Add a dragger to enable shape dragging
            this.getWwd().addSelectListener(new BasicDragger(this.getWwd()));

            // Create and set an attribute bundle.
            ShapeAttributes attrs = new BasicShapeAttributes();
            attrs.setOutlineMaterial(new Material(WWUtil.makeRandomColor(null)));
            attrs.setOutlineWidth(2d);

            ArrayList<Position> pathPositions = new ArrayList<Position>();
            pathPositions.add(Position.fromDegrees(26, 75, 1e4));
            pathPositions.add(Position.fromDegrees(20, 80, 1e4));
            Path path = new Path(pathPositions);
            path.setAttributes(attrs);
            path.setVisible(true);
            path.setAltitudeMode(WorldWind.RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
            path.setPathType(AVKey.GREAT_CIRCLE);
            RenderableLayer propertiesLayer = new RenderableLayer();
            propertiesLayer.addRenderable(path);


            /*--------------------------------------------TABBED PANE CODE--------------------------------------------*/
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
            horizontalSplitPane.add(ta);
//            JPanel p2=new JPanel();
//            JPanel p3=new JPanel();

            tp.setBounds(50,50,200,200);
            tp.add("Layers",layerPanel);
//            tp.add("SQL",p2);
//            tp.add("help",p3);
            horizontalSplitPane.add(tp);
            tp.setSize(400,400);
            tp.setLayout(null);
            tp.setVisible(true);

            // Add the layer to the model.
            insertBeforeCompass(getWwd(), propertiesLayer);

            List<String> markers = new ArrayList<String>(1);
            markers.add(String.valueOf(new BasicMarker(Position.fromDegrees(90, 0), new BasicMarkerAttributes())));
            MarkerLayer markerLayer = new MarkerLayer();
//            markerLayer.setMarkers(markers);
            insertBeforeCompass(getWwd(), markerLayer);
        }
```

**ERROR BLOCK**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=55088:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\NasaWorldWind\classes;D:\NasaWorldWind\jogl-all.jar;D:\NasaWorldWind\gluegen-rt.jar;D:\NasaWorldWind\gdal.jar;D:\DOWNLOADS\postgresql-42.2.1.jre7.jar" avr_dbpostgisapp.ApplicationTemplateTest
java.lang.InstantiationException: avr_dbpostgisapp.ApplicationTemplateTest$AppFrame
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at avr_dbpostgisapp.ApplicationTemplateTest.start(ApplicationTemplateTest.java:410)
    at avr_dbpostgisapp.ApplicationTemplateTest.main(ApplicationTemplateTest.java:586)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at avr_dbpostgisapp.ApplicationTemplateTest.connstart(ApplicationTemplateTest.java:502)
    at avr_dbpostgisapp.ApplicationTemplateTest.main(ApplicationTemplateTest.java:588)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to manage the addition of the JTabbedPane to the left component of the JSplitPane.

The code is as follows,

**CODE BLOCK**

```
JSplitPane horizontalSplitPane = new JSplitPane();
            horizontalSplitPane.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(200, 200);
            JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
            JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
            p1.add(ta);
            p2.add(ta);
            JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
            tp.add("Layers",layerPanel);
            tp.add("SQL",p2);
            horizontalSplitPane.setLeftComponent(tp);
            horizontalSplitPane.setRightComponent(wwjPanel);
            horizontalSplitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
            horizontalSplitPane.setContinuousLayout(true);
```